# Can we come up with a cool design for our voting and badge icons?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Currently, we have the Stack Exchange standard voting and badge icons:

[image] [image]

What would it take (beyond someone with a great idea and some graphics ability) to get some cool/appropriate icons like they have at [Bicycles.SE](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com)?

[image][image]

Comment: Would like to reference a meta post about the site design http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251938/icon-sets-used-for-all-sites. I was trying to get information about other site designs. People here should understand that they will take our suggestions. I though that I might be able to make my own set.

Comment: Here's my contribution for *worst* idea: an upcut spiral router bit for upvote and a downcut spiral router bit for downvote!

Answer (score 8):

I believe graphic design elements like this are usually done when a site graduates from Public Beta to being a full site - that's the biggest part of that process.  You also get a better icon and specific colors/background/etc.

From what I recall, they have some graphic designers on staff who propose a design when it's close to graduation time, and then we have an opportunity to provide feedback then.  But that's months and probably years away.  :)

Comment: I should think we are getting a _little_ ahead of ourselves with this right now. Still not bad to at least consider.

Comment: Ah, but look at question #6: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/

Comment: Hmm.. I might take a stab at this then.

Comment: Keep the ideas flowing guys! Any artifacts you post in meta will be considered when our team gets the go ahead to provide the custom design for your site.

Answer (score 4):

I have zero graphic design skill, but what about a dovetail profile around the up/down arrows and a round saw blade (circular saw/table saw/miter saw) around the star?  We could also have a 4- or 6-pointed star with some stacked dado chippers, but I wonder if that could be made to look abstract enough for newcomers to realize it's supposed to be a clickable star.

Comment: Maybe use the circular saw blade as the badge icon, and a hammer as the favorite. You know, tack it in place!  Of course, that's not particularly intuitive...

Comment: I like the saw idea for the badge icon too, but maybe we should stick with the star for favorites, since it's more universally used.

Answer (score 3):

I am reasonably certain that site theming does not occur until a site has officially "graduated."  It will be a while until that happens, at which point the SE Design Team will give the site a makeover.

Comment: When the time comes, can you point them to this thread for some ideas?

Comment: @FreeMan when the time comes I'll shall be here :)

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking having a table saw (top third of the blade over a line) for the upvote and a circular hand saw (bottom third of the blade, under a line) for the downvote. Although dovetails are nice, too.